# Order alphabetically but according to a parent

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given the table below of categories, would there be a way where I return the names alphabetically, but include the ones with a parent_id under its parent?

| ID | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Hardware |
| 2 | NULL | Software |
| 3 | NULL | Networking |
| 4 | 1 | Desktop |
| 5 | 1 | Printer |
| 6 | 1 | Laptop |
| 7 | 2 | Office |
| 8 | 2 | Windows |
| 9 | 2 | Other |
| 10 | 3 | Outage |
| 11 | 3 | Firewall |
| 12 | NULL | Accounts |
| 13 | 12 | New Account |
| 14 | 12 | Password Reset |

This query is used with PHP, so I could always organized them through php code but it got me thinking if there was a way to do this in the query directly. I'm drawing a blank on how to approach this.  This particular example only goes 1 level deep with children, so a solution that handles that I would be fine with at the moment. But is there an approach that could allow multiple levels of children as well?

For example, if I just pulled only parent categories (rows with a null parent_id) and ordered by name I'd have Accounts, Hardware, Software, Networking. But I'd like to have:

| ID | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | NULL | Accounts |
| 13 | 12 | New Account |
| 14 | 12 | Password Reset |
| 1 | NULL | Hardware |
| 4 | 1 | Desktop |
| 6 | 1 | Laptop |
| 5 | 1 | Printer |
| 3 | NULL | Networking |
| 11 | 3 | Firewall |
| 10 | 3 | Outage |
| 2 | NULL | Software |
| 7 | 2 | Office |
| 9 | 2 | Other |
| 8 | 2 | Windows |

Comment: Please include the expected output as well.

Comment: I've added a table of the desired output

Comment: Do the categories that appear as a parent ever have a non null parent themselves?

Comment: @ysth, no. If their parent_id is null then nothing will be above them.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution, much simpler than I was expecting. This will work for my example, but will not take into account multiple levels deep.

```
SELECT p.id, p.parent_id, p.cat_name, COALESCE(c.cat_name, p.cat_name) as g
FROM category p
LEFT JOIN category c
ON p.parent_id = c.id
ORDER BY g, parent_id, cat_name
```

To account for children who's parent may be a child itself, I do not yet have a solution but feel like that answer lies in using **WITH RECURSIVE**.

Comment: You probably don't  need to return `g` either, just put the condition in the Order By

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware I could use coalesce in the order clause.